# How to stream data to an output blob binding with Azure Function?

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to retrieve a big file from an API and save it on an Azure Storage account, so I am designing an Azure Function. I don't want my code to download all the data and then write all the data, I can have a data input stream from this API, and I would like to stream data to an output blob.

Here is a small example

```
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    name = "stranger"

    # mimick a stream
    for char in name:
        outputblob.set(char)

    return func.HttpResponse(
        "Hello "+name,
        status_code=200
    )
```

Here is my **function.json**:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputblob",
      "path": "container/hello.txt",
      "connection": "connection_storage"
    }
  ]
}
```

And when I open the file **container/hello.txt** from my storage, it contains only the last character, "r", and weighs only 1 byte.

I think that `outputblob.set(data)` overwrites the data to the output blob.

How can I stream data and append it to my output blob? I'd rather use output blob bindings, but I can use "ContainerClient" objects.

(EDIT: In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python#usage), they specify that we can use

> Streams as func.Out[func.InputStream]

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [`upload_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#upload-blob-data--blob-type--blobtype-blockblob---blockblob----length-none--metadata-none----kwargs-) method of `azure.storage.blob.BlobClient` with `blob_type="AppendBlob"`:

```
import logging

import requests
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient


def stream_to_blob(url: str, filename: str) -> int:
    """Download a stream from an URL into a blob." """
    logging.info("Downloading...")
    sess = requests.Session()
    get_fichier = sess.get(url, stream=True)
    get_fichier.raise_for_status()

    # Connect to the storage account :
    connection_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=..."
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_str)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("mycontainer")
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)
    filesize = 0

    # Appending data one block at a time
    # We can upload data up to 4 MB at a time
    for block in get_fichier.iter_content(4 * 1024 * 1024):
        filesize += len(block)
        logging.info(
            "Appending %d bytes to the blob (total = %d)...", len(block), filesize
        )
        blob_client.upload_blob(block, blob_type="AppendBlob")

    logging.info("Downloading finished")
    return filesize
```

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, when you are mimicking a stream you are overriding the content of the output blob each iteration, that's why at the end you are receiving the last letter.

Solution: assign the whole array of bytes to the `outputblob`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python for the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I sometimes **can't** retrieve all the data in memory at once then write it to the output blob. For instance I could download a 10 GB file from an API, this would not fit in the memory.

Comment: I am not a python expert but I guess there is a possibility to "append" bytes to an existing stream, maybe that's a way to go?

Comment: I you find such a way, please write an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: The simplest way would be to copy the current content, append new data manually and set it to the blob: out=outputBlob.read().decode("utf-8")+char
outputblob.set(out)

Comment: Or to implement AppendBlobService from Azure Storage SDK :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.appendblobservice.appendblobservice?view=azure-python-previous

Comment: Running `outputBlob.read()` does not seem efficient to me: if I want to write 1 GB of data by blocks of 1 MB, I will need to write 1 MB to the blob, then read the content, load 1 MB into the memory, write 2 MB, read & load 2 MB, write 3 MB, etc, effectively writing a total of... 500 GB.

Comment: And warning, AppendBlobService is deprecated, the documentation you linked is for "Python Legacy"